# Display button with append in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, append

I use the code below to append and display button where the data come from a json file. But the data-role seem not to be use and my button look like text, do you have an idea of the error?

```
<section id="main" data-role="page" >
    <ul id="allRepos" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.fr/wp-content/themes/responsive-child-theme/test.php',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data){
                var i, repo;
                $.each(data.repositories, function (i, repo) {
                    $('#allRepos').append('<li>'
                    + '<h4>' + repo.timestamp + '</h4>'
                    + '<p>' + repo.message + '</p>'
                    + '<div data-role="content">'
                    + '<a onclick="playAudio(\'' + repo.message + '\')" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Play</a>'
                    + '</div>'                      
                    + '</li>'
                    );
                });
                $('#allRepos').listview('refresh');
            }});  
</script>
```

Comment: `$("ul [data-role=button]").button();` after appending items.

Comment: Thanks Omar that's made the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Omar, here is the working code :

```
<section id="main" data-role="page" >
    <ul id="allRepos" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.mywebsite.fr/wp-content/themes/responsive-child-theme/test.php',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data){
                var i, repo;
                $.each(data.repositories, function (i, repo) {
                    $('#allRepos').append('<li>'
                    + '<h4>' + repo.timestamp + '</h4>'
                    + '<p>' + repo.message + '</p>'
                    + '<div data-role="content">'
                    + '<a onclick="playAudio(\'' + repo.message + '\')" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Play</a>'
                    + '</div>'                      
                    + '</li>'
                    );
                    $("ul [data-role=button]").button();
                });
                $('#allRepos').listview('refresh');
            }});  
</script>
```